# VBA how to get property out of row for "Each Row"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going insane trying to figure this relatively simple thing out. How do I extract the property in a "For Each" row loop?

Here's a version of my code

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim curr_region as range

set wb = ThisWoorkbook
set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
set curr_region = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'this range is a 9 columns and 24 rows

For each curr_row in curr_region.Rows
      curr_row(1,2).Value2 ''''error occurs here

Next
```

The loop works up until I try to get the value out of curr_row and I don't undestand what's wrong. In the locals window, I can see the `"Value2"` property (is that the right term?) which expands into `"Value2(1)"` which further expands into `Value2(1,1)....Value2(1,9)`

How do I access `Value2(1,2)` as it appears in the locals window? I've tried the following:

```
curr_row(1,2).Value
curr_Row(1,2).Value2
curr_row.Value2(1,2)
curr_row.Value(1,2)
curr_row(1,2)
curr_row(1)
```

Nedless to say I'm going insane because none of these work, what am I doing wrong here? Beyond this specific example, what is the general syntax to getting to a property of an object? I thought once I can see it locals, it would be a straightforward mapping, but I'm so confused. Just driving me insane here.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the value.  Something like `debug.print curr_row(1, 2).Value2` should return the value.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I still get an error if I use my original code with a debug.print. I tried looking up the value in the debug in the immediate window as well, and no dice. It seems I have to use cells for some reason as pointed out below, but I have no idea why rows doesn't work

Comment: Probably because you did not declare `curr_row` at all so it will default to a variant rather than a range object.  It is good practice to always declare your variables. In the VBA GUI, you can enforce this by `Tools/Options/Editor/Code Settings` and selecting `Require Variable Declaration`. This will place `OPTION EXPLICIT` at the top of each inserted module (and you can also manually add this to modules created before you selected this option). This will be extremely useful in catching typos, variables of the incorrect type, etc.

Comment: Oh, forgot to suggest to declare `curr_row` as a range object.  `Dim curr_row as Range`

Comment: You would find it helpful to 'cast' the loop control variable (which is implicitly Variant in your code) to the correct Type.  Then you will gain the advantage of intellisense from the cast variable.  e.g. the first two lines after the for each could be DIm myRow as Excel.Row, Set myRow =curr_row.  and to then use myRow from then on in place of Curr_row.  myRow will give you the correct intellisense for the excel Row object.  If you haven't done so already please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and take a look at the code inspections.  Its quite an eye opener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems straightfoward to use `Cells` here:

```
curr_row.Cells(1, 2).Value2
```

For example:

```
Dim foo As Variant
foo = curr_row.Cells(1, 2).Value2
Debug.Print curr_row.Cells(1, 2).Value2
curr_row.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "bar"
```

Best practice is to declare all your variables:

```
Dim curr_row As Range
```

Comment: hi, I'm specifically looking for a value in a specific column so I thought going by row was the best method. I have a bigger question, though, how would i ge tthe value if I do it by rows? Why is the syntax wrong? I thought it was just object.map.map

Comment: `Cells` gives you a value in a specific column, right? Here it would be in the 2nd column of the row.

Comment: hmm when I do that I still get an error. So if I do curr_row.Cells(1,2).Value2 I get an object doesn't support this property or method. Same as error as before I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening

Comment: Well you have to do something with the `.Value2`, e.g. `Debug.Print curr_row.Cells(1, 2).Value2`

Comment: @The locals object window shows a branching from "Value2" to "Value2(1) " and then "Value2(1)" branches off into individual values in the cells.  I wonder if that's contributing

Comment: `.Value2` of a multi-cell range is a 2D array.

Comment: you're totally right. I'm stupid. Thank you! I'm still really preplexed why it works with cells but not rows? They seem to have an identical layout in the Locals window

Comment: Welcome to the magic of `Range`s in Excel VBA. Your row is just a multi-cell range.

Comment: well that makes me feel better. I'm a novice so I don't know where to even figure something like this out, there doesn't seem to be great documentation. Very frustrating. I'll accept your answer in a minute, it's making me wait. Tyvm for your help